# Ограничение на тип для Generic-методов

Tags: c#, generics, c#-faq

Как в C# для обобщенного метода задать ограничение только на целочисленный тип *(byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong)*

```
public T example<T>(this T value) where T (...)????
```

Comment: [Говорят](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34186), что нативной поддержки нет, но наверное можно как-то [так](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22425077).

Comment: @post_zeew спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .Net 7 всем числовым типам добавили интерфейс `INumber<TSelf>`,
что позволяет его использовать как ограничение.

```
static T Add<T>(T left, T right) where T : INumber<T>
{
    return left + right;
}
```

Целочисленным типам добавили `IBinaryInteger<TSelf>`, использовать его можно так же.

Comment: `IBinaryInteger<T>` для целочисленных

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, поправил. Зря я так о runtime-команде ))

Answer (score 4):

Никак. В качестве ограничений для обобщений могут использоваться только [следующие конструкции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d5x73970.aspx):

- where T : struct
- where T : class
- where T : new()
- where T : <base class name>
- where T : <interface name>
- where T : U, где U -- другой параметр-тип

В качестве обходных путей можно использовать следующие варианты:

- создать перегрузку для каждого типа
- оставить параметр `T` без ограничений и проверять тип в начале метода (это, по понятным причинам, более "слабое" решение)